# Trouble with finding parent

Tags: javascript

I'm using Greasemonkey to enhance a grid-based website with some highlighting. I want to add an outline to the cell the user clicked in. To do this I need to highlight the parent of the cell. Otherwise it takes 2 clicks to add the border highlighting I plan to use.

This is inside an eventlistener for click, passing "elem"

The clicked cell is available in the click event - I've checked this by verifying it's attributes. They key attrib is :

```
data-test="siteQty-sometext&row=XXXX%^&site=YYYY"
```

where row and site are unique values for each cell

The parent always has the same class "rrrr ssss tttt" defined like this, where YYYY is site from the data-test field above.

```
<div class = "rrrr ssss tttt" colid="sqYYYY".. >
```

so overall it's

```
<div class = "rrrr ssss tttt" style="width: 100px;, left: 20px; colid="sqYYYY"> 
    <div class = "mmm nnn ooo", data-test=data-test="siteQty-sometext&row=xxxx%^&site=YYYY"">
</div>
</div>
```

with the second div being the clicked element, and the first div being the one I want to highlight (outline with a border).

I've tried

```
var upclass = "mmm nnn ooo";
var mydad = elem.target.closest(upclass);
```

and

```
var mydata = elem.target.parentNode;
```

both give undefined

n00B, so what am I missing ?

Comment: It looks like you're over complicating it. I also think you've missed posting some important details.

Comment: Keep troubleshooting up the chain... what is `elem.target`? What is `elem`? Are they the things you think they are?

Comment: `elem.target` is correct, I have verified it's attributes (loop thru `target.attributes`) to be those of the clicked element.   

but .parentnode = Null

Comment: I noticed that when I click in the cell the `<div` changes to a `<input` . Does this make a difference ?

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
var upclass = "mmm nnn ooo";
var mydad = elem.target.closest(upclass);
```

change to  uplcass var's value with `.` for class:

```
var upclass = ".mmm nnn ooo";
var mydad = elem.target.closest(upclass);
```

Should work.

**update: use this:**

```
var upclass = ".mmm";
```

Comment: Great ideas..thanks
 
"mmm nnn ooo" is not a unique string, there are many elements with this class. So my bad here in not explaining that.  I need the particular parent of the clicked cell.

Comment: @Col.in, just suggestion.. try to use one class only like only `mmm` or ` nnn` to select in jquery. Better if you use readable class name following proper naming convention.

Comment: is it not working? If not please  check the updates

Comment: note that `mmm` is the class of the clicked element. I actually want to find the `rrrr ssss` element.

Comment: what do you get in your `mydad` variable? if parent `div`, then get the classes by mydad.attr("class").

Comment: `mydad=[object HTMLDivElement]`

Comment: try these now `mydad.getAttribute("class") `  or `mydad.attr("class")` ?